# Configurable product and its associated product creation using soap api documentation is not in magento api guide.any idea?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, simple-product, soap-api-v2

I am trying to create a configurable product and its associated product using magento soap api.Product created successfully but configurable product linking with associated product is not working properly guys any idea?Here is my code

```
<?php 
$client = new SoapClient('https://sample.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');

// If some stuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('username', 'Password');

// get attribute set
$attributeSets = $client->catalogProductAttributeSetList($session);
$attributeSet = current($attributeSets);
print_r($attributeSet);
$result = $client->catalogProductCreate($session, 'simple',72, 'product_sku0002', array(
    'categories' => array(2),
    'websites' => array(1),
    'name' => 'Product name',
    'description' => 'Product description',
    'short_description' => 'Product short description',
    'weight' => '10',
    'status' => '1',
    'url_key' => 'product-url-key',
    'url_path' => 'product-url-path',
    'visibility' => '4',
    'price' => '100',
    'tax_class_id' => 1,
    'meta_title' => 'Product meta title',
    'meta_keyword' => 'Product meta keyword',
    'meta_description' => 'Product meta description',
    'additional_attributes' => array(
        'single_data' => array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'color',
                'value' => 'Red', // Id or label of color, attribute that will be used to configure product
            )
        ),
    ),
));
var_dump ($result);
$result = $client->catalogProductCreate($session, 'configurable',72, 'Configurable_product_sku0001', array(
    'categories' => array(2),
    'websites' => array(1),
    'name' => 'Confihurable Product name',
    'description' => 'Product description',
    'short_description' => 'Product short description',
    'weight' => '10',
    'status' => '1',
    'url_key' => 'product-url-key',
    'url_path' => 'product-url-path',
    'visibility' => '4',
    'price' => '100',
    'tax_class_id' => 1,
    'meta_title' => 'Product meta title',
    'meta_keyword' => 'Product meta keyword',
    'meta_description' => 'Product meta description',
    'associated_skus' => array('product_sku0002'),
    'price_changes' => array(
        array(
            'color' => array(
                'Red' => '0'
            )
        ),
    ),
));
var_dump ($result);
?>
```

Comment: Hi @Jithesh did you got the answer for this, if you have an answer please share to me